# How can I get Vagrant to start the server on startup?

Tags: vagrant

I want Vagrant to start the Play server in the /vagrant/ folder every time I do vagrant up. Putting @reboot on the crontab doesn't work because the script runs before the /vagrant/ folder is connected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of using crontab, have you tried using [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)?

Vagrant emits a "vagrant-mounted" event when the shared folder is mounted, so you could create an upstart conf file, say `/etc/init/play.conf`, to run when that event is emitted:

```
description "Play server"
start on vagrant-mounted

pre-start script
    [ "$MOUNTPOINT" == "/vagrant" ] || stop
end script

... rest of config file for starting Play server ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I got the error `/bin/sh: 1: [: =: unexpected operator`, so I just uncommented that line.

Comment: Oops! I edited the post so that the syntax is correct.

Comment: Can `start on vagrant-mounted MOUNTPOINT=/vagrant` work as well?

Comment: For my upstart script `start on vagrant-mounted` doesn't work for some reason. Don't know why and don't know how to debug it at all.

Answer (score 44):

I found using a seperate vagrant provisioner with the option `run : "always"` a lot easier, eg:

`config.vm.provision :shell, path: "yourStartUp.sh", run: "always", privileged: false`

See https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html for full doc.

Comment: The provided link doesn't say anything about `"always"`. Maybe this was removed in an newer version.

Comment: @RafaelEyng the docs for it are at https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/basic_usage.html, search for "RUN ONCE OR ALWAYS"

Comment: Retested in 2017. Works like a charm. This is the best answer and still up-to-date.